# Intento ejecutar e programa pero me da error en PRINTF, no se porque

Tags: javascript, java

Intente ejecutarlo pero no me dejó y quise revisarlo pero no encuentro la falla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hay nada en tu "pregunta"

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, siempre trata de colocar tu codigo entre las etiquetas `codigo` y no como imagen, el error que se te presenta no es el `printf`, es que no has puesto un `;`

Exactamente en el while antes de ese printf.

```
while(seguir != 'n');
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh gracias amigo te debo una grande

Comment: Dale no te preocupes, si tienes más interrogantes, te invito a leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)